# restful_template in Mapproxy and WMTS

Tags: wmts, mapproxy

I'm trying to display a WMTS from https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/EPSG/2056/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml with mapproxy, but I have some trouble to get the restful_template of the wmts service in Mapproxy right.

In the capabilities.xml of the official WMTS source I can read the following url:

```
<ResourceURL format="image/jpeg" resourceType="tile" template="https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.swissimage/default/{Time}/2056/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.jpeg"/>
```

But as I could see, the parameter {Time} is not known in Mapproxy. And the {TileMatrixSet} is also missing in the url given by the capabilities.)

I had to add the {TileMatrixSet} in to the restful_template of the service,as mapproxy wouldn't start without it.  ([https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.13.1/services.html#web-map-tile-services-wmt](https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.swissimage/default/current/2056/25/746/328.jpeg)s)

This gave me following mapproxy.yaml

```
services:
  wmts:
    restful: true
    kvp: true
    restful_template: /1.0.0/{Layer}/default/{TileMatrixSet}/2056/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.{Format}
  
sources:

  swisstopo: 
    type: tile
    grid: current
    url : https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.swissimage/default/current/2056/%(z)s/%(y)s/%(x)s.%(format)s
      
layers:
  - name: ch.swisstopo.swissimage
    title: ch.swisstopo.swissimage
    sources: [test_wms_cache]
      
    
caches:
  test_wms_cache:
    sources: [swisstopo]
    grids: [current]
    #meta_size: [2, 2]
    format: image/jpeg
    
grids:
  current:
    srs: 'EPSG:2056'
    bbox: [2420000.0, 1030000.0, 2900000.0, 1350000.0]
    bbox_srs: 'EPSG:2056'
    origin: nw
    res: [4000,3750,3500,3250,3000,2750,2500,2250,2000,1750,1500,1250,1000,750,650,500,250,100,50,20,10,5,2.5,2,1.5,1,0.5,0.25,0.1]
```

As I was missing a TileMatrixSet, I named my grid after it (current). As a result I tried to request 2 times the same tile, once in the original resource, once in mapproxy. But the result aren't the same tiles:

[Origninal Tile Request](https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.swissimage/default/current/2056/25/746/328.jpeg)

[image: Original Tile]

[Mapproxy tile request](http://127.0.0.1:8080/wmts/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.swissimage/default/current/2056/25/746/328.jpeg)

[image: Mapproxy Tile]

I guess the diffrence of location is because of the {Tilematrixset} parameter, but I don't know how to handle this correctly.

Gladly I will try out any suggestions, I can feel like it's just a step away from working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misconfigured you BBOX.

```
[2420000.0, 1030000.0, 2900000.0, 1350000.0]
```

should be

```
[2420000.0, 130000.0, 2900000.0, 1350000.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was wrong. I try another one ;) since I stumbled around with swisstopo services too these days.

your URL

`https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.swissimage/default/current/2056/%(z)s/%(y)s/%(x)s.%(format)s`

has wrong order of x and y you should try

`https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.swissimage/default/current/2056/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.%(format)s`

Cheers